# Stuck building a javascript object dynamically

Tags: javascript, object, dynamic

I have a bunch of interactive activities which have been written in flash by reading in all the parameters from an XML file. We are moving away from FLASH and so I am writing a script which will read in the XML elements I need and dynamically build a javascript object containing all the elements and their properties. In the end, I pass the object through a JSON.stringify() and pass back a JSON-ized version.

I'm reading in the XML using an ajax call with JQUERY and then a mix of JS and JQUERY. I like jquery for its DOM selectors.

I'm learning all this stuff as I go along and i'm not a developer by trade so i've hit a wall when I get to the point where I need to process a bunch of elements with .each(). I'm guessing its a syntax thing though i'm not sure. Everything was working great until it came time to adding the "panels" which in the XML looks like +...
I have to process each panel.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "activity.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        var activity = {
            title : {
                text: $(xml).find('title').text(), 
                xpos: $(xml).find('title').attr('xpos'), 
                ypos: $(xml).find('title').attr('ypos')
            },
        rubric : {
                text: $(xml).find('rubric').text(), 
                xpos: $(xml).find('rubric').attr('xpos'), 
                ypos: $(xml).find('rubric').attr('ypos')
            },
        panels: {
                $(xml).find('panel').each(function() {
                    panel :{width: $(this).attr('width'), 
                    height: $(this).attr('height'), 
                    xpos: $(this).attr('xpos'), 
                    ypos: $(this).attr('ypos')
            }});// end .each()
        }// end panels object
   });//end ajax.get(xml)   

   var activity_json = JSON.stringify(activity);
```

Im certain its not done this way but i don't know how it should be.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Put up a simplified version of this on JSfiddle - it's tough to catch the problem without seeing original data.

One thing I've run into in the past is that you have to make sure XML is valid - some flash routines are far more forgiving than web browsers. Have you checked that all of activity.xml validates correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem must be here

```
panels: {
            $(xml).find('panel').each(function() {
                panel :{width: $(this).attr('width'), 
                height: $(this).attr('height'), 
                xpos: $(this).attr('xpos'), 
                ypos: $(this).attr('ypos')
        }});// end .each()
```

Rewrite your code as follows:

```
 var activity = {
        title : {
            text: $(xml).find('title').text(), 
            xpos: $(xml).find('title').attr('xpos'), 
            ypos: $(xml).find('title').attr('ypos')
        },
    rubric : {
            text: $(xml).find('rubric').text(), 
            xpos: $(xml).find('rubric').attr('xpos'), 
            ypos: $(xml).find('rubric').attr('ypos')
    },
    panels : []
 };



  $(xml).find('panel').each(function() {
           var data = {
                panel :{
                    width: $(this).attr('width')
                }, 
                height: $(this).attr('height'), 
                xpos: $(this).attr('xpos'), 
                ypos: $(this).attr('ypos')
           }
           activity.panels.push(data);
  });
```

**EDIT**

You are breaking the syntax of the object literal. You should init an array and finish the object declaration. Then iterate over your collection and fill your object's `panels` property with appropriate value.

**EDIT**

Yeah. I see what do you mean.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/8cnwK/) is the fiddle that iterates over your dom elements. I used the native JavaScript api. I'm not very familiar with, say, jQuery2XML.

Comment: Thanks! yep its definitely in there (the panels part) because when I comment it out it works fine. I've tried your solution after messing with it for a little while, there was a small error. Just had to move activity.panels.push(data) to after the closing bracket for the data object (after the second } not the first). So this looks good except now i'm not sure how to access the properties for each one. panels.panel[x].width didnt work for me.

Comment: @Nuevallorker I've updated the answer. I used just indeces instead of names. But a little bit of digging and you'll find out how to refer to the attributes via their names. Cheers.